# App android error when reboot phone

Tags: android, reboot

I am doing app Android.1 Activity and 1 Boardcast Recieve.

```
public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       if     (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    }
    else{
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }


        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}
 }
```

And manifestfile

```
<receiver
android:name=".PhonecallReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
</intent-filter>
```

When run , app run fine.But when I reboot phone, app error at :

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
```

How to fix error.Thank

Answer (score 0):

You should check null for intent.
For example

```
if(intent != null && !TextUtils.isEmplty(intent.getAction())
{

}
```

and plz post your log error in here.

Answer (score 0):

do you have below code in Manifest ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
```

Please post your error log in here